# Can AssertJ isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively ignore a field?

Tags: java, jpa, assertj

I need to compare a JPA Entity with expected value ignoring IDs. AssertJ has this method

```
assertThat(actualEntity).isEqualToIgnoringGivenFields(expectedEntity, "id");
```

which compares two objects ignoring ID, but my actualEntity has a list of inner entities, that have IDs too. Is there a method that would recursively ignore field `id` in the inner objects as well?

I saw there is this method

```
assertThat(actuactualEntitya).isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively(expectedEntity);
```

but I don't see an option how to tell that I want to ignore `id` recursively. Is there any way, how to achieve that using AssertJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can, use the recursive comparison for that https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison which lets you specify fields to ignore by name or regex: https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison-ignoring-fields

Comment: Thanks, I probably have too old version of AssertJ and this method is not there. I'll check int the team if upgrade is possible.